# Azure Data Studio does not provide any way to connect re-opened query window to database

Tags: azure, azure-data-studio

I closed Azure Data Studio (ADS) with a blank query tab open.  When I restarted the app the blank query tab opened with it.  I wrote a query in the tab then realised there appears to be no way to set the connection.  Is there a way to connect this tab to a database?

The previously unsaved query tab reopens without a hotbar at the top of the window (the hotbar being the menu with Run, Connect, etc buttons):

[image]

Right-clicking on the tab doesn't offer any way to connect that I can see:

[image]

In contrast, tabs that were previously saved before closing ADS reopen showing the hotbar:

[image]

And tabs opened since ADS was restarted, which are still unsaved, also show the hotbar:

[image]

So it's only unsaved tabs present when ADS restarts that don't show the hotbar.

Am I missing something?  Is there a way to connect this unsaved tab to a database?  Or is the only option to open another query tab and copy the query I wrote to the new tab?

Comment: Could you refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-data-studio/) once.

Comment: @Balaji: Any particular link on that page?  It's easy enough to create a new query window that will connect to a database, and copy the contents of the existing query window into the new one.  However, it seems to me like I shouldn't have to do that. I feel it should be possible to connect from the existing query window but I don't see any obvious way to do that.

Comment: There's normally a connect bar at the top of the window, including connection options. You appear to have removed it

Comment: You can see, for example, in this [random image I found of ADS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6ywB.png) there are Run, Cancel, (Dis)Connect, and Change Connection buttons, as well as a drop down for the database context. You have disabled that hotbar.

Comment: @ThomA: I haven't removed or disabled the hotbar at the top of the query window, it was like that when Azure Data Studio started up.  Any new query window I open _**does**_ have the hotbar with the Connect and other controls.  It's only the window that was open when Azure Data Studio was previously shut down, that reopened automatically when I started Azure Data Studio again, which doesn't have that hotbar.  Any idea on how to turn it back on for that query window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I managed to get the Connect and other controls to display at the top of the old window was to save it as a .sql file.  Once saved the appropriate controls became visible at the top of the window.

I guess that Azure Data Studio must use the file extension of a window to determine if it's a SQL window or not, at least when it opens an old, unsaved, window from the previous session.

When reopened the window retained the previous title it had before it was closed: "SQLQuery_1", without a file extension.  When the window was created in the previous session Azure Data Studio had recognised it as a SQL window, and had displayed the Connect and other controls at the top.  But when it was reopened after Azure Data Studio restarted it looks like Azure Data Studio no longer recognised it as a SQL window, presumably because it had no file extension.

Answer (score 0):

> I missing something? Is there a way to connect this window to a database? Or is the only option to open another query tab and copy the query I wrote to the new tab?

Open your Azure data studio and open setting by pressing **`ctrl`+`,`** and make menu bar and activity bar visible

[image]

[image]

Then Create a SQL serverbconnection by going Connections >> New Connection >> Fill the appropriate details anbd connect.

[image]

Then you will see the bow option to connect appropriate database.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PratikLad.  Unfortunately that didn't work.  When I clicked the New Connection button, selected a recent connect and clicked Connect it just opened a new database window, it didn't make the Connect and other controls visible for the tab that was already open.